# How to use letter with SI unit in table using siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I want this

I (μA)  and this  ΔC (nF)

but cannot seem to be able to use letter (instead off numbers) and how do I put the parenthese too.

Thks in advance.

```
 \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
     \begin{center}
     \begin{tabular}{| l | d{2} | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |} \hline   
      Matérieaux    &\textrm{C}(nF) &$\pm\Delta$C(nF) &$d(mm)$  & $\pm \Delta$d(mm) &     D(mm) &$\pm\Delta$D(mm)   &$\varepsilon_r$    &$\pm\Delta \varepsilon_r$ \\    \hline
      A         &4.69   &1.172  &0.11   &0.01   &225.00     &1.00   &1.40 &0.51 \\   \hline
      B         &5.64   &1.729  &0.14   &0.01   &225.00     &1.00   &2.24 &0.87 \\   \hline
      C         &1.23   &0.136  &0.79   &0.01   &225.00     &1.00   &2.77 &0.37 \\   \hline
      Air           &0.29   &0.037  &1.32   &0.01   &225.00     &1.00   &1.09   &0.16   \\   \hline
    \end{tabular}
   \caption{Tableau des résultats pour la méthode directe}\label{Tab: 6}
 \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Would like to use something like this insted

```
 \begin{tabular}{| l | d{2} | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |} \hline   
      Matérieaux    &\SI{C}{(\nano\farad)}  &\SI{\pm\DeltaC}{(\nano\farad)} \\   \hline
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, the units of measure are placed beneath the labels, which also saves space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp] % not just 'h!'
\centering % not a center environment

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=3.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Matérieaux &
 {$C$} &
 {$\pm\Delta C$} &
 {$d$} &
 {$\pm\Delta d$} &
 {$D$} &
 {$\pm\Delta D$} &
 {$\varepsilon_r$} &
 {$\pm\Delta \varepsilon_r$} \\
&
  {(\si{\nano\farad})} &
  {(\si{\nano\farad})} &
  {(\si{\milli\meter})} &
  {(\si{\milli\meter})} &
  {(\si{\milli\meter})} &
  {(\si{\milli\meter})} \\
\midrule
A     &4.69   &1.172  &0.11   &0.01   &225.00     &1.00   &1.40 &0.51 \\
B     &5.64   &1.729  &0.14   &0.01   &225.00     &1.00   &2.24 &0.87 \\
C     &1.23   &0.136  &0.79   &0.01   &225.00     &1.00   &2.77 &0.37 \\
Air   &0.29   &0.037  &1.32   &0.01   &225.00     &1.00   &1.09 &0.16 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Tableau des résultats pour la méthode directe}\label{Tab: 6}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

With `siunitx` it's easier to set up the columns for alignment at the decimal point; if you want a decimal comma, just do

```
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
```

in the preamble.

You don't need to use the `booktabs` model for the table, but I highly recommend it.

[image]

Comment: What is the [table-format=1.3]..

Comment: @SebastienComtois The column contains numbers with one digit in the integral part and three digits in the decimal part.

Comment: is there a way for me to change the[ Table 1 -> to french ->Tableau 1],under the table. I'm already using babel french though.... and it doesn't seem to do it

Comment: @SebastienComtois Adding in the preamble `\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand\tablename{Tableau}}` should do.

Comment: la ringrazio molto professore lo apprezo

Comment: @SebastienComtois Non c'è di che! (You're welcome!)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\noindent 1 \si\micro A and $\Delta$C (\si\nano F). \\
\SI{800}{\milli\meter}
\SI[mode=text]{1.23}{J.mol^{-1}.K^{-1}} \\
\SI{.23e7}{\candela} \\
\SI[per-mode=symbol]{1.99}[\$]{\per\kilogram} \\
\SI[per-mode=fraction]{1,345}{\coulomb\per\mole}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: not at all,I want to use the siunitx packages, so it would be more of $\SI{800}{\milli\meter}$

Comment: What errors you are getting then?

Comment: Thks     @Croco I really appreciate it

Comment: But could I also input the farad ampere stuff in there

Comment: in there where?

Comment: To be honest this is the first time I knew about this package. I just went to manual and it seems well organized. Please read page 7 for mixing numbers with letters `\SI`

Comment: Woaw,I really need to get some rest. Thank you for pointing me there.

Comment: Life is so much easier with manuals :) @Croco, your a saint.

Comment: Why not `\SI{1}{\micro\ampere}` and `\si{\nano\farad}`? I'd say that `\si\micro A` is wrong.

Comment: @egreg I agree with you, that's exactly why I asked the question in the first place. But as you can see in Croco's anwer, everything is there.

Comment: @SebastienComtois The fact that the output seems correct doesn't mean the input is good.

Comment: @egreg, I acknowledge your concern, but can't you read\SI{800}{\milli\metre} and the reference (p.7)to the manual wich explicitly write that you can use \si\{\coulomb}

Comment: The reference to the manual is actually  the best answer anyone could have written, but you can still edit the answer for future references