# tabular column size width not fitting all content

Tags: tables, columns

I am using the following code, based on [How to use letter with SI unit in table using siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270475/how-to-use-letter-with-si-unit-in-table-using-siunitx) to create a table.

How can i make the column wide enouth to fit the content. Whats the best way for the dimensions column setup?

[image]

```
\begin{table}[!htp] % not just 'h!'
\centering % not a center environment
\begin{tabular}{
        @{}
        l
        S[table-format=1.1]
        S[table-format=1.3]
        S[table-format=1.2]
        S[table-format=1.2]
        S[table-format=1.2]
        @{}
    }
    \toprule
    Inductor &
    {$size$} &
    {$inductance$} &
    {$sensitivity$} &
    {$dc resistance d$} &
    {$SRF$}\\
    &
    {(\si{\milli\meter})} &
    {(\si{\milli\henry})} &
    {(\si{\milli\volt\per\ampere\meter})} &
    {(\si{\ohm})} &
    {(\si{\kilo\hertz})} \\
    \midrule
    Premo       &8.6x3x2.7 &18.5 &90 &165 &300  \\
    TDK         &7x12x33   &8.6   &23 &112 &135     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:inductor}

\end{table}
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but do not use math mode (`$`)  in order to get italic text. Use `\textit` instead.

Comment: Are you sure about `\milli\volt\per\ampere\meter`? Shouldn't it be `\milli\volt\per\ampere\per\meter`?

Comment: To be correct it should be (mV)/(A/m), but this is the same as (mV*m)/A. But i am not familiar with the interpretation of this writing terminology.

Answer (score 3):

At a standard line width, the table is slightly overfull, so I use a `tabular*` trick; you'll need to check whether this works and the intercolumn space is adequate, otherwise you may resort to `\small`.

The second column is not `S`, but you should use `\num` for its entries. Set properly the number of digits for the other columns.

Please, don't use math mode for italics: it's not meant for that purpose.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % let TeX do the calculations
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  c
  S[table-format=2.1]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Inductor &
  {\itshape size} &
  {\itshape inductance} &
  {\itshape sensitivity} &
  {\itshape DC resistance $d$} &
  {\itshape SRF}\\
&
  {(\si{\milli\meter\cubed})} &
  {(\si{\milli\henry})} &
  {(\si{\milli\volt\per\ampere\meter})} &
  {(\si{\ohm})} &
  {(\si{\kilo\hertz})} \\
\midrule
Premo & \num{8.6x3x2.7} & 18.5 & 90 & 165 & 300 \\
TDK   & \num{7x12x33}   &  8.6 & 23 & 112 & 135 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{A table}\label{xyz}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very smart trick to get a tabular to fit.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no real sense to use a S column specifier for the size column. However, use the notation `{...}` if you have not a number in the column cell and, of course, use proper specifications for numbers: 3.1 (`iii.d`) reserves space for three integers and one decimal

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
        @{}
        l
        S[table-format=1.1]
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=3.1]
        S[table-format=3.1]
        @{}
    }
    \toprule
    Inductor &
    {\itshape size} &
    {\itshape inductance} &
    {\itshape sensitivity} &
    {\itshape dc resistance d} &
    {\itshape SRF}\\
    &
    {(\si{\milli\meter})} &
    {(\si{\milli\henry})} &
    {(\si{\milli\volt\per\ampere\meter})} &
    {(\si{\ohm})} &
    {(\si{\kilo\hertz})} \\
    \midrule
    Premo       &{8.6x3x2.7} &18.5 &90 &165 &300  \\
    TDK         &{7x12x33}   &8.6   &23 &112 &135     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

\end{document}

[image]

Comment: You might also want to correct the wron use of math mode to get italic text.

Comment: thanks, I looked only for the `S[...]` ... :-(   Now edited